# remove blank space before wrapper div

Tags: css

i want to remove blank spaces which is there. i am a layman user. please forgive me if i am doing a silly mistake. thanks in advance. see image in which space is there and refer to code also.[image: image of design of page]

html code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>CSS</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="wraper">

    <div id="header">
    Header
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    Side
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    Content
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    Footer
    </div>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css code:

```
    #wraper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:800px;
    height:1000px;
    background:#FCFCFC;
    }
    #header{
    background:#CFCFC0;
    height:100px;
    width:800px;
    }
    #content {
    float:right;
    width:600px;
    height:700px;
    background:#C0C0C4;
    }
    #sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:700px;
    background:#CFFCCC;
    }
    #footer {
    clear:both;
    background:#C0CC0C;
    height:200px;
    width:800px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove padding and margin from body and html elements

```
html, body {
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

As a good practice you could load a `normalize` or `reset` stylesheet as a first css (e.g. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to remove style discrepancies among browsers

Answer (score 3):

```
*{  
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
}
```

give `padding` and `margin` manually to each tag later

Answer (score 0):

Using a css reset like http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset/reset-min.css or http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ will help.

Answer (score 0):

try this **[demo](http://jsbin.com/uhirov/1/)**

only add this to the top of your css

```
html, body {
   margin: 0 auto;padding:0;
}
```

**0 for the top and bottom margin and auto for the left and right margin to make it in the center**

Answer (score 0):

Another option as specified by @Fabrizio is to use normalize CSS.

https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css